# Increment a sum total with DispatchTimer C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to increment a total every second with a DispatchTimer in a little WPF app I have. Basically for every second the amount needs to increase by .095...cents. The running total then needs to display inside a label. I think I have the formula correct but I'm not sure how I get the grandTotal to display and be updated every second, some help would be appreciated.

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
}


private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        decimal costperSec = 0.095703125m;
        decimal total = costperSec + costperSec;
        decimal grandTotal = decimal.Add(total, costperSec);
        // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        lblSeconds.Content = grandTotal;
        //For testing
        //lblSeconds.Content = "-" + "$" + DateTime.Now.Second;
}
```

Comment: You're not storing the value anywhere. You need to keep the vale and then increment it.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by that, the values are stored? costperSec, total and grandTotal? Or do you mean outside the DispatchTimer? Do I need some sort of foreach loop to pick up the tick then I do my calculations.?

Comment: Yes, you need to have a variable outside the method to keep track where you're going. At the moment you're calculating the same number every time. No need for any loops for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your grandTotal is only "stored" inside the dispatchTimer_Tick method scope.

What you need to do is, save the variable outside the scope:

```
private decimal grandTotal = 0;

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        decimal costperSec = 0.095703125m;
        decimal total = costperSec + costperSec;
        grandTotal += decimal.Add(total, costperSec);
        // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        lblSeconds.Content = grandTotal;
        //For testing
        //lblSeconds.Content = "-" + "$" + DateTime.Now.Second;
}
```

Scopes is a common thing in programming. Especially C-like languages. Here are some basics about scoping:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: thanks for your comment, however the grandTotal outside the dispatchTimer still only has the grandTotal from one tick just like it did inside the timer, every second I want the value to increase, debugging this the grandTotal still resets every tick.

Comment: Woops.. My bad.. I edited the answer to use the += operator on grandTotal.